# force heroku / django to use local database

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I have a django based herokuapp site.  I set everything up a long time ago and am now unable to get things working with a local instance of postgresql.  In my settings file, I updated:

```
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

to work with a local database:

```
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost/appDB')
```

When running foreman, I can view the site, but the database is not currently populated (although I did create the empty DB).  Running:

```
heroku run python manage.py dumpdata
```

Returns the contents of the remote (herokuapp) database, while a syncdb command results in "Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)".  So it looks like I'm still contacting the remote database.  I'm pretty sure the postgresql DB is setup correctly locally; how can I force the app to use it?

I'm sure this is simple, but I haven't seen anything useful yet.  I did try

```
export DATABASE_URL=postgres:///appDB
```

but that hasn't helped.

Cheers

Comment: you want to use you local DB in heroku?

Comment: To test and develop the Django app locally

Comment: It's not clear to me that I should be running the heroku commands rather than the same django commands without the heroku interface, however, when I do this (inside a virtualenv) e.g. python manage.py syncdb, I get import errors on the django modules.

Comment: Oh, now I feel stupid! Turns out I just needed the edits mentioned above to the settings file and then run the regular django commands outside of the virtual env.

Comment: Well, if you need to test locally your database, isn't necessary to run heroku commands.